# Convert Byte Array to image and display in Razor View

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using **EF 4.1 Code First** and for the sake of simplicity, let's say I have the following Entity class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

I have managed to create a working Create View that allows the Addition of a Person object into the Database.

But when I come to display the details for a Person, I get stuck on displaying the image. After doing some research, I have the following:

```
// To convert the Byte Array to the author Image
public FileContentResult getImg(int id)
{
    byte[] byteArray = DbContext.Persons.Find(id).Image;
    return byteArray != null 
        ? new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg") 
        : null;
}
```

And in the View where I am attempting to list the Person details, I have the following to get the Image to display:

```
<img src="@Html.Action("getImg", "Person", new { id = item.Id })" alt="Person Image" />
```

However the above is not working, my image source **[src] attribute returns empty**.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("getImg", "Person", new { id = item.Id })" alt="Person Image" />
```

You need `Url.Action` and not `Html.Action` because you just want to generate an url to the `GetImg` action. `Html.Action` does something [entirely different](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

Comment: But what if it is byte array of some PDF file. How can we display a link to preview or may be a link to download the pdf. .

Comment: What if it is not an image. How can we handle that. Obviously we cannot put img src tag for pdf's

Answer (score 69):

There's an even easier way of doing this if you already happen to have the image loaded in your model:

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image)" />
```

Doing this way you do not need to go to the server again just to fetch the image `byte[]` from the database as you're doing.

Comment: But what is it's a pdf file or word file. How can we display a link of may be preview the content in razor code. provided in the controller action we have the byte array .

Comment: **@Unbreakable -** I would recommend you to ask that as a separate question on Stack Overflow rather than playing with comments. And you could post here the link so users can see it.

Comment: it converts byte array malformed. with # chars. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to display a dynamically loaded SVG image from a Model property in a Razor MVC page is to use Html.DisplayFor(..) in combination with .ToHTMLString().  For my case, have a base 64 SVG Image+XML data string stored in the model property named Image.  Here is my code:

```
<img src='@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Image).ToHtmlString()' />
```

This seemed be the only way I was able to get the SVG image to display properly in Chrome, FireFox and IE.

Cheers