# display byte array image in MVC4 view

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

i'm trying to display an image in my view.

i've written an Image helper:

```
    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static FileContentResult Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        byte[] imageData, string mimeType)
        {
            return new FileContentResult(imageData, mimeType);
        }
    }
```

myImage - is a byte array.

```
<img src="@Html.Image(myImage, "image/jpeg")" />
```

but my image is not displayed...

when i look at the source code all i see is:

```
<img src="System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult">
```

anyone? :)

Comment: Please see this question's answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560830/convert-byte-array-to-image-and-display-in-razor-view

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it you are returning the `FileContentResult` in between the quotes of the `src=""`.

I see what you are trying to do, but in order for this to work, the `<img src=>` needs to request the URL of the image not simply put the `byte[]` in the src. So you'll need to set up an action method that takes in some parameter and returns the `FileContentResult`.