# mvc4 get image in view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

First of all, i have used this way in another controller and it works perfectly, now i copied and paste it in another controller, but it didnt work.

i want to get an image from my controller.

i used this code in controller

```
[Authorize]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public FileContentResult getPassportImg(int tenantID)
        {
            byte[] image = db.Tenants.Find(tenantID).passportImage;
            if (image != null)
            {
                return new FileContentResult(image, "image/jpeg");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and i make breakpoints throw it and the data is being retrieved correctly.

in the view i do this

```
<div class="display-field">
        <img src="@Url.Action("getPassportImg", "Tenant",  new { tenantID = Model.ID })" alt="asdasdf" />
    </div>
```

but when i run my application, it's not get the image. Can you
Please help me resolve this

Comment: Check the src that it generates if its the right url. Cause it seems to me that you  are setting the src as FileContentResult.

Comment: @WannaCSharp yes it is an image in the controller and i want to show it in the view, where is the wrong in the src? tell me please who to know, i am sure it is correct because i just copied and pasted the code from a previous working project

Comment: What's the value of the src? It's supposed to be a link to the image like `'/Images/ProfiePic.jpg'`

Comment: @WannaCSharp when i see the html of the page i see this `<img src="/Tenant/getPassportImg?tenantID=3"` which is exactly the controler, also i make breakpoints in the controller and checked the value, they are 100% correct

Comment: @WannaCSharp the image is a byte array, i get it from database and show it in the view

Comment: I'm searching for possible solution. Anyway check the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560830/convert-byte-array-to-image-and-display-in-razor-view

Comment: @WannaCSharp sorry buddy, i was just nervious , forgive me please

Comment: No worries buddy. Sorry I couldn't be any more help. Your code seems right to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40430/discussion-between-marco-dinatsoli-and-wannacsharp)

Comment: @WannaCSharp the second answer didnt work, i wish it works

Comment: @WannaCSharp I left the code as is and read an image from disk with System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes( and it works fine for me too.